# Selenium through the chrome driver does not want to clear the field after entering the text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, autotest

Selenium must enter text in the search field, press enter, then clear it and enter new text. But here's the problem when I use firefox everything works fine, but the chromedriver for some reason does not want to delete the old text.

```
def test_pacient_search(app):    
    app.patient_search(patient_fullname="Name1")
    time.sleep(2)
    app.patient_search(patient_fullname="Name2")
```

```
def patient_search(self, patient_fullname):
    wd = self.wd        
    patient_search = wd.find_element_by_class_name("components__input__input")
    patient_search.click()
    patient_search.clear()
    patient_search.send_keys(patient_fullname)
    patient_search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird issue, but I have observed quite few time that `.clear()` does not work properly.

In those cases generally what I'd do, is to simulate `ctrl+a` and then `delete`, make sense ?

so instead of

```
patient_search.clear()
```

do this :

```
patient_search.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
patient_search.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
```

Comment: Was it helpful ?if yes, can you accept this answer so that it will be available in green color for future readers. In case if you would like to accept this answer, please feel free click on check mark which is right aside with voting buttons. I'd appreciate your time and response on this